# AngularJS select with ng-options not updating referenced object property in the parent scope

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

My select is populating with the contents of the model, but when I select an option, the model does not update.

I'm using ng-options, not ng-repeat and my ng-model is an object on the parent scope, not a primitive, so I think I've avoided the "child-scope" issues I've seen on similar posts.  I've recreated the problem on jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/bobweil/wfdjrej5/

When the user clicks on a row in the table, a small form shows up below that row, permitting a new status value to be selected for that row for posting to the backend service.

Here's my javascript:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('TaskCtrl', function HomeController($scope, $filter) {

$scope.statusMasters = [{
    "Id": 1,
        "DisplayOrder": 100,
        "Text": "Review"
}, {
    "Id": 2,
        "DisplayOrder": 200,
        "Text": "New"
}, {
    "Id": 3,
        "DisplayOrder": 300,
        "Text": "Working"
}, {
    "Id": 4,
        "DisplayOrder": 400,
        "Text": "Complete"
}]

$scope.tasks = [{
    "taskId": 1000,
        "Descr": "My first task",
        "statusId": 1
}, {
    "taskId": 2000,
        "Descr": "My second task",
        "statusId": 1
}, {
    "taskId": 3000,
        "Descr": "My third task",
        "statusId": 1
}];

$scope.selectedTask = null;
$scope.newTaskStatus = {};
$scope.opGroup = "A";

$scope.selectTask = function (thisTask) {
    $scope.selectedTask = thisTask;
    $scope.newTaskStatus = {};
    $scope.newTaskStatus.taskId = thisTask.taskId;
    $scope.newTaskStatus.statusId = thisTask.statusId;
};
$scope.isSelected = function (thisTask) {
    if (thisTask.hasOwnProperty('taskId')) {
        return $scope.selectedTask.taskId === thisTask.taskId;
    } else return false;
};
```

});

And here's my html:

```
<div ng-controller="TaskCtrl">
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Task #</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>StatusId</th>
            <th>Status Text</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="item in tasks" ng-click="selectTask(item)" ng-switch on="isSelected(item)">
        <tr>
            <td>{{item.taskId }}</td>
            <td>{{item.Descr}}</td>
            <td>{{item.statusId}}</td>
            <td>{{statusMasters[item.statusId - 1].Text}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-switch-when="true">
            <td colspan="10">
                <div>Debug: contents of new task status object: <pre>{{newTaskStatus | json}}</pre>

                </div>
                <label>Select a new status for task {{newTaskStatus.taskId}}:</label>
                <select ng-model="newTaskStatus.taskId" ng-show="(opGroup == 'A')" class="form-control" ng-options="rec.Id as rec.Text for rec in statusMasters | orderBy : 'DisplayOrder'"></select>
                <select ng-model="newTaskStatus.taskId" ng-show="(opGroup == 'B')" class="form-control" ng-options="rec.Id as rec.Text for rec in statusMasters | orderBy : 'DisplayOrder'"></select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the issue is you are trying to set a click event on the tbody, you need to set the ng-click on the row (tr).

Secondly, unless it is needed for another reason, I wouldn't duplicate the values from the "selectedTask" into a "newTaskStatus" when you are planning on changing the status and sending back that value, it can all be done with one object on the scope.

Third, you could clean up your .js a little by changing the 'ng-switch on' to do the check if it is selected.  It replaces an entire function with a comparison.

I would do something like this.

```
 <tbody ng-repeat="item in tasks" ng-switch on="selectedTask.taskId == item.taskId">
        <tr ng-click="selectTask(item)">
            <td>{{item.taskId }}</td>
            <td>{{item.Descr}}</td>
            <td>{{item.statusId}}</td>
            <td>{{statusMasters[item.statusId - 1].Text}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-switch-when="true">
            <td colspan="10">
                <div>Debug: contents of new task status object: <pre>{{selectedTask | json}}</pre>
                </div>
                <label>Select a new status for task {{selectedTask.taskId}}:</label>
                <select ng-model="selectedTask.statusId" ng-show="(opGroup == 'A')" class="form-control" ng-options="rec.Id as rec.Text for rec in statusMasters | orderBy : 'DisplayOrder'"></select>
                <select ng-model="selectedTask.statusId" ng-show="(opGroup == 'B')" class="form-control" ng-options="rec.Id as rec.Text for rec in statusMasters | orderBy : 'DisplayOrder'"></select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

With the .js I would remove the unnecessary items:

```
    $scope.selectedTask = null;
$scope.opGroup = "A";

$scope.selectTask = function (thisTask) {
    $scope.selectedTask = thisTask;
};
$scope.isSelected = function (thisTask) {
    if (thisTask.hasOwnProperty('taskId')) {
        return $scope.selectedTask.taskId === thisTask.taskId;
    } else return false;
};
```

I forked your jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/0pufgr9s/) to demonstrate what I mean.  Good Luck!

Comment: The issue was apparently having the ng-click on the tbody instead of on the row.  This fixed my problem.  Apparently, when I clicked the desired option in the select list, that fired the click event on the tbody and reset everything back the way it was.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: By the way, I noticed that when I created the fiddle, I made my ng-model = "newTaskStatus.taskId" instead of "newTaskStatus.statusId" like it should have been.